# Combinatorics/Probability unordered lists

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I don't really understand these unordered lists problems such as...

Q: John goes to a store and buys 10 pieces of fruit from the selection of apples, bananas,peaches and pears at random.  What is the probability that he bought:

a.At least one kind of each fruit?
b. Exactly two apples?
c. No pears?
d. No more than 2 peaches?

I have all the answers, but I don't know how they work. Such as for the first one.
$$
\frac{C(6+3,2)}{C(10+3,3)}
$$

The 6 is because at the most you have to buy 1 of each, so 10-4 = 6. The ten on the bottom is because you have to buy 10 total....then I'm lost. My professor said its because we are choosing the dividers between the fruit not the actual fruit. "We aren't choosing the numbers, but the dividers between the fruit.  So you need 1 less divider than items." I vaguely get what she is talking about with dividers, but I'm still unsure.

Like if we just set it up as a ternary sequence choosing 3 apples, 3 bananas, 2 peaches, and 2 pears....

AAA|BBB|PP|EE

Any help walking through this problem? I'm confused when its either a probability or counting problem, I just have a probability example at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Stars and Bars" for this type of problem; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

In part a),
to find the denominator, you can set up 3 dividers (to separate the 4 kinds of fruit) and 10 dots (to represent the fruit chosen).  The number of ways to arrange the 3 dividers and 10 dots is just $\dbinom{13}{3}$.

For the numerator, you can line up the 10 dots, and then choose 3 of the 9 gaps between the dots to place the dividers; so the numerator should be $\dbinom{9}{3}$.

[Equivalently, you can first select one of each kind of fruit. Then you have 6 pieces of fruit left to choose, so now you can use the same reasoning as in finding the denominator.]